# fwrite a file removed by another process

Tags: logging, fwrite

```
fwrite(str, strlen(str), 1, g_poFp);
```

This is a log file. My process writes some log information in this file using `fwrite`. But today the file was removed by some one. My question is that, how to code to monitor the remove action!